Getting scopes of a request built by Kiota
When building a custom authentication provider for a Kiota-generated SDK, I'd like to know which scopes are required for the request I'm about to authenticate. Is this information available somewhere in the generated code? I was hoping that maybe the additionalAuthenticationContext argument would include this data but that doesn't seem to be the case.
